# excel vba copy value from a column and paste value in a cell

Tags: excel, copy-paste, transpose, vba

I have data like below. First column belongs to column A and second column belongs to column B.

```
1   q
1   q
2   q
2   q
2   q
3   q
```

I would like to insert empty rows whenever values in column A change. To insert rows I am using the macro from [this site](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1868-excel-insert-blank-row-when-value-changes.html).

```
'select column a before running the macro
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()
'Update 20140716
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After that I would like to copy each set of values from column A and paste in a cell in column C. While pasting them, I would like to paste values in ***a cell*** in ***a row format (by concatenating them) and separating them by a space***. In below case, cells c1 should have `1 1`, cell c4 should have `2 2 2` and cell c8 should have `3`

How to do this? I tried to record macro using first copying each set of values then pasting them after transposing into a row. But I am having hard time copying values again and pasting them within a single cell

Comment: What do you mean by wanting to paste values into a single cell?  Are you trying to concatenate all the values together?

Comment: yes, concatenate value and separate them by a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Before and After for code bellow:

[image] [image]

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()
    Dim rng As Range, itms As Variant, cel As Range, i As Long, firstRow As Long

    Set rng = Range("A3:A1000")
    firstRow = rng.Row - 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rng.Cells(i, 1).Value2 <> rng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value2 Then
            If i < rng.Row - 1 Then
                Set cel = rng(i, 1)
            Else
                rng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                Set cel = rng(i + 1, 1)
            End If
            With cel.CurrentRegion
                itms = .Columns(1)
                If .Columns(1).Rows.Count > 1 Then itms = Join(Application.Transpose(itms))
                cel.Offset(0, 2) = itms
            End With
        End If
        If i = 1 Then Exit For
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Comment: would it be possible to change code so that workRng is always A3:A1000?

Comment: i tried `Set workRng = Range("A3:A1000")` and commented `xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"`
   `Set workRng = Application.Selection`
  `Set workRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, workRng.Address, Type:=8)`, but it didnt work

Comment: Sure - I'm making the change now

Comment: sure, I will wait for your answer

Comment: I made the update - please try the new version and let me know if there are any issues

Comment: it looks good. I tested it. I will let you know if something goes unexpected

Answer (score 1):

I have this function that works like the built-in `Concatenate()`, but gives you filtering abilities. I doesn't seem to fully help you might give you another approach to your ultimate goal.

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As Range, Condition As Variant, _
        ConcatenateRange As Range, Optional Separator As String = ",") As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strResult As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If CriteriaRange.Count <> ConcatenateRange.Count Then
        ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
        If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
            strResult = strResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    If strResult <> "" Then
        strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(Separator) + 1)
    End If
    ConcatenateIf = strResult
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```